# Não estou conseguindo fazer o preenchimento dos <td> dinamicamente com AJAX e PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

tenho um código com um formulário que quando fazer uma pesquisa e lista as atividades do funcionário. Estou utilizando PHP e AJAX, porém a tabelanão está sendo preenchida. Vejam o Código:

```js
$('#formulario-consulta').submit(function(e)
   {   
    e.preventDefault();
    var formulario = $(this);
    var retorno = inserirFormulario(formulario);
   
   });

   function inserirFormulario(dados)
   {
    $.ajax
    ({
     type:"POST",
     data:dados.serialize(),
     url:"interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
     async:false
     
    }).done(function(data)
    {
     var atividades = "";
     
     $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor)
     {
      atividades += '<tr>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.COD + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.EMPRESA + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.TIPO_DE_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.STATUS + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_VENCIMENTO + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_INICIO + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.codigo + '</td>';
      atividades += '</tr>';
     });
     
     $('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);
     
     
    }).fail(function()
    {
     alert("Não deu certo");
     
    }).always(function()
    {
     
     
    });
    
   }
```

```html
<?php
 
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 
 require_once("conexao-com-banco.php");

?>


<?php
    // Determinar localidade BR
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
  
 //INICIANDO A SEÇÃO DO USUÁRIO CONECTADO
 session_start();
 
 if ( !isset($_SESSION["user_portal"]) )
 {
  header("location:index.php"); // SE NÃO ESTIVER CONECTADO, RETORNA PARA A PÁGINA DE LOGIN
 }
 else
 { 
  // SE HOUVER ÊXITO NA CONEXÃO, REALIZAR UMA MENSAGEM DE BOAS DINDAS.
  
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $hora = date("H");
  if($hora > 06 AND $hora < 12)
  {
   $mensagem_boasvindas = "Bom Dia, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . " !";
  }
  else if($hora >= 12 AND $hora < 18)
  {
   $mensagem_boasvindas = "Boa Tarde, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . " !";
  }
  else
  {
   $mensagem_boasvindas = "Boa Noite, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . " !";
  }
  
 }
   
 $user = $_SESSION["nome"];
?>


<?php
 //Consultas ao banco de dados
 require_once("interface-consulta-banco.php"); // CHAMANDO ARQUIVO DE CONSULTA AO BANCO PARA PREENCHER OS CAMPOS "AUTOMATICAMENTE DO FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA COM INFORMAÇÕES DO USUÁRIO

?>


<?php
      
 require_once("interface-consulta-comentarios.php"); // CHAMANDO ARQUIVO QUE PREENCHE OS CAMPOS DE RETORNO E FEEDBACK
  
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Sistema - JCA</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      
  <link href="_css/estilo-telainterface.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DESTA PÁGINA -->
  <link href="_bootstrap4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->
      
  
</head>


<body>  
  
    
  <div class="container-fluid">
   
   <header>
   
    <h1>SISTEMA WEB</h1>
    <p><i>"Uma mente que se abre a uma nova idéia jamais voltará ao seu tamanho original"</i></p>
   </header>
   
   
   <!-- DIV COM MENSAGEM DE BOAS VINDAS AO USUÁRIO -->
   
   <div id="mensagem">
    <h5><?php echo $mensagem_boasvindas ?></h5>
   </div>
   
   
   
   <div class="row">
    
    <!-- INÍCIO DA DIV COM O FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="pesquisa">
    
     <form id="formulario-consulta"> <!-- FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->
      <div class="form-inline">   
      
        <div class="row">
        
         <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="botao-resumo" style="margin-top: 0">Resumo por Status</button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar:</h5>
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosTodos" value="Todos" class="form-control" checked> Todos: 
            </label>
           </div>
           
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosComum" value="Comum" class="form-control"> Comum: 
            </label>
           </div>
           
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosExtra" value="Extra" class="form-control"> Extra: 
            </label>
           </div>
           
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosUrgente" value="Urgente" class="form-control"> Urgente: 
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar por data de:</h5>
           <div class="radio">
            <select name="data" id="data" class="input-sm form-control">
             <option  value="Inicio">Início </option>
             <option  value="Finalizacao">Finalização </option>
             <option  value="Vencimento" selected>Vencimento </option>
            </select>
           </div>
                                  
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar por período:</h5>
           De: <input type="date" name="dataInicial" id="dataInicial" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:40%;">
           Até: <input type="date" name="dataFinal" id="dataFinal" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:40%;">
                                        
          </div> 
         </div>
        </div>

       
       <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          
         <div class="">
         
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>COD</h5>
            <select  name="cod" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
            <?php
             while($linha_cod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_cod))
             {
            ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?>
             </option>

            <?php
             }
            ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div> 
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Empresa</h5>
            <select name="empresas" id="empresas" class="input-sm form-control" style="width: 100%">
            <option></option>
             <?php
             while($linha_empresas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_empresas))
             {
             ?> 
              <option value="<?php echo $linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"]; ?> "> 
               <?php echo utf8_encode($linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"]); ?>
              </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div> 
           
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Tributação</h5>
            <select name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
            <?php
             while($linha_tributacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_tributacao))
             {
            ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"]; ?>
             </option>

            <?php
             }
            ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Atividade</h5>
            <select name="atividade" id="atividade" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
             <?php
              while($linha_atividade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_atividade))
              {
             ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo utf8_encode($linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"]); ?>
             </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Status</h5>
            <select name="status" id="status" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
             <?php
              while($linha_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_status))
              {
             ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_status["STATUS"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo utf8_encode($linha_status["STATUS"]); ?>
             </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
           <h5>Pesquisar</h5>
           <input name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Enviar">
           
          </div>
                    
         </div>
        </div>              
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div> 
    
   </div>   
      

      
   <div class="row">
    
    <!-- DIV QUE EXIBE O RESULTADO DA PESQUISA DO FORMULÁRIO -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="resultado-pesquisa">
          
     
     <!-- DIV QUE EXIBE AS INFORMAÇÕES DE RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
     
     <div class="col-lg-12" id="exibicao">
      
      <!-- TABELA QUE EXIBE DINAMICAMENTE COM O PHP OS RESULTADOS DA CONSULTA AO BANCO -->
      
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="resultado-exibicao">
       
       <thead>
        <tr><th>COD</th><th>EMPRESA</th><th>TRIBUTAÇÃO</th><th>TIPO DE ATIVIDADE</th><th>STATUS</th><th>DT.VENC</th><th>DT.INÍCIO</th><th>DT.FIM</th><th>Código</th></tr>
       </thead>
       
       <tbody id="registros-atividades">
        
        
        
       </tbody>
       
       
      
      </table>
      
      <!-- FORMULÁRIO OCULTO PARA FAZER O SUBMIT QUE ENVIA AS INFORMAÇÕES DA TABELA ACIMA PRO BANCO -->
      
      <form action="interface.php" id="meuForm" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="campo1"/>
      </form>
      
      
     </div>
     
     
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <!-- DIV PARA EXIBIÇÃO DO RETORNO DA CONSULTA DOS CAMPOS DETALHES E FEEDBACK -->
   
   <div class="row" id="detalhesfeedback">
    
    <!--DIV QUE EXIBE O CAMPO DETALHES COM O RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 panel panel-primary" id="detalhes">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">DETALHES</h4>
     </div>
       
       
     <div class="panel-body">
     <p>
     <?php 
      if(isset($executarDetalhes))
      {
        foreach ($executarDetalhes as $key => $value)
        {
       $formatacao_detalhe = utf8_encode($value);
       echo "$formatacao_detalhe";
        }
      }
     ?>
     </p> 
     </div>
           
    </div>
    

    <!--DIV QUE EXIBE O CAMPO FEEDBACK COM O RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 panel panel-primary" id="feedback">
     
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">FEEDBACK DA GERÊNCIA / RESPONSÁVEL SETOR</h4>
     </div>
       
       
     <div class="panel-body">
      <?php 
      if(isset($executar_select_feedback))
      {
        foreach ($executar_select_feedback as $key => $value)
        {
       $formatacao_feedback = utf8_encode($value);
       echo "$formatacao_feedback";
        }
      }
      ?>
     </div>
           
    </div>
    
    <!-- DIV COM OS BOTÕES QUE EXECUTAM AÇÕES NO BANCO -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="botoes-detalhes-feedback">
        
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-inserir-detalhes">Inserir Detalhes</a></button>
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-success"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-reabrir-atividades">Reabrir Atividades</a></button>
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-reabrir-atividades">Sem Movimento/Arquivo</a></button>
     
    </div>
    
    
    <!--DIV MODAL QUE ABRE QUANDO CLICAMOS NO BOTÃO INSERIR DETALHES -->
    <!--
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="modal-inserir-detalhes">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close"
          aria-label="close"
          data-dismiss="modal">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Insira um Comentário</h4>
       </div>
       
       <div class="modal-body">
        
        <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-inserir-destalhes">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comentario">Comentário</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="comentario-inserir-detalhes" id="comentario-inserir-detalhes" style="resize: none"></textarea>
         </div> 

         <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="enviar-detalhes" id="enviar-detalhes">
         
        </form>

         
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    -->
    
    
   </div>
   
   
   
  </div>
    
</body> <!-- FIM DO BODY -->
</html> <!-- FIM DO HTML -->

<?php
 // Fechando Conexão
 
 mysqli_close($conecta);
 
 
?>


<!-- ARQUIVO interface-resultado-pesquisa.php -->

<!-- CONSULTA GERAL DO BANCO  QUE RETORNA O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA DA PÁGINA INTERFACE.PHP -->

<?php
 
 require_once("conexao-com-banco.php"); // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO
   
 
 
 if(isset($_POST["enviar"])) //REALIZA A AÇÃO SE O BOTÃO "ENVIAR" FOR ACIONADO
 {
  //PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
  
  $tipodedata = utf8_decode($_POST["data"]);
  $pegaropcao   = utf8_decode($_POST["optionRadios"]);
  $dataInicial = $_POST["dataInicial"];
  $dataFinal  = $_POST["dataFinal"];
  $cod = $_POST["cod"];
  $empresas   = utf8_decode($_POST["empresas"]);
  $tributacao = utf8_decode($_POST["tributacao"]);
  $atividade  = utf8_decode($_POST["atividade"]);
  
  $status = utf8_decode($_POST["status"]);
  $responsavel = $_SESSION["nome"];

  
  //VERIFICA QUAL É O TIPO DE ATIVIDADE ENTRE AS EXTRAS, URGENTES OU COMUM
    
  if($pegaropcao == "Comum")
  {
   $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  = 'C'";
  
  }
  else if($pegaropcao == "Urgente")
  {
   $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  = 'U'";
  
  } 
  else if($pegaropcao == "Extra")
  {
   $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  = 'E'";
  
  } 
  else 
  {
   $tipodeatividade = " AND EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM  <> 'N'";
  
  } 
  
  
  //IF PARA VERIFICAR POR QUAL TIPO DE DATA O BANCO IRÁ FILTRAR
     
  if (!isset($dataInicial) AND !isset($dataFinal)) 
  {
   
   if($tipodedata = "Vencimento")
   {
    $variavel = " AND DT_VENCIMENTO BETWEEN '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal'"; 
   }
   else if ($tipodedata = "Finalizacao")
   {
    $variavel = " AND DT_FIM BETWEEN  '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal'";
   }
   else if($tipodedata = "Inicio")
   {
    $variavel = " AND DT_INICIO BETWEEN '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal'";
   }
  } 
    
  else
  { 
   $variavel = " ORDER BY DT_VENCIMENTO asc"; 
  }
 
  
  //REALIZA A CONSULTA NO BANCO DE DADOS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DO FORMULÁRIO
  
  $pesquisar    = "SELECT COD, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO, TIPO_ATIVIDADE, STATUS, DT_VENCIMENTO, DT_INICIO, DT_FIM, codigo FROM tbl_atividades";
  $pesquisar    .= " WHERE COD like '%$cod' AND EMPRESAS like '%$empresas' AND TRIBUTACAO like '%$tributacao' AND TIPO_ATIVIDADE like '%$atividade' AND RESPONSAVEL = '$responsavel' AND STATUS like '%$status' $tipodeatividade $variavel";
         
  $operacao_consulta = mysqli_query($conecta, $pesquisar) or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados"); 
  
  if($operacao_consulta)
  {
  
  
   $retorno = array();
   while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($operacao_consulta))
   {
    $retorno[] = $linha;
   }  
   

   echo json_encode($retorno);
  }
  
  

  
 }
  
?>
```

**Agora veja a imagem da Interface**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Certo seria ao clicar no botão enviar, as atividades fossem listadas naquela "quadro" abaixo dos botões.

Vale lembrar que quando faço a consulta diretamente no banco, o resultado aparece corretamente.

Se puderem me ajudar, ficaria grato!

Imagem do erros apresentados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria legal você colocar o código do arquivo `interface-resultado-pesquisa.php` também. Pois é dali que vem o problema.

Comment: Eu tinha colocado, é pq tinha colocado no código daqui como "inserir-resultado-pesquisa", foi um erro de digitação aqui mesmo. Mas já corrigi. Se puder me ajudar eu ficaria muito grato. Estou a umas 5 horas tentando resolver isso.

Comment: Mas Thiago, é importante você colocar todo o código do ARQUIVO `interface-resultado-pesquisa.php` pois é lá que gera o resultado json certo? Esse json que é usado dentro do ajax certo? É ali que mora o problema, EU ACHO!

Comment: Mas eu coloquei. Está todo código ali na pergunta. Vc não conseguiu ver ? Termina com um echo json_encode($retorno). É a última parte do código.

Comment: Acabei de ver, deculpa...

Comment: Faz o seguinte... Altere esta linha... `$('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);` que está no ajax por esta : `$('#registros-atividades').html(data);` só para ver o que mostra no html

Comment: O que acontece, é que o retorno da resposta não está no "formato json" por completo, deve estar mostrando algum erro, ou mensagem de alerta do php que não está deixando você resgatar o json no javascript

Comment: O erro está claro... **erro de sintaxe** ... mas o porque é que precisa ser entendido.

Comment: Fiz o que você falou mas não mostrou nada. To achando que o erro é no PHP. Mas já olhei várias vezes o código e não encontro o erro.

Comment: Mas aparece algum erro no console? Fazendo o que eu pedi?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90818/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-thiago-petherson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após uma longa [discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90818/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-thiago-petherson), identificamos que o código não passava pelo `if(isset($_POST["enviar"]))`. Isso acontece porque esse valor não é enviado pelo ajax quando é serializado, pois ele vem do botão que é clicado para enviar o formulário.

Tem uma [resposta sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866762/9303032) aonde o auto diz que :

> O jQuery serialize()é bastante explícito sobre NÃO codificar botões ou
>   enviar entradas, porque eles não são considerados "controles de
>   sucesso". Isso ocorre porque o método serialize () não tem como saber
>   qual botão (se houver algum) foi clicado.

Esse comentário foi recuperado de uma nota do próprio [site do JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) que diz:

> Nota: Somente "controles bem-sucedidos" são serializados para a
>   string. **Nenhum valor de botão de envio é serializado**, pois o
>   formulário não foi enviado usando um botão. Para que o valor de um
>   elemento de formulário seja incluído na sequência serializada, o
>   elemento deve ter um nameatributo. Valores de caixas de seleção e
>   botões de opção ( inputs do tipo "rádio" ou "caixa de seleção") são
>   incluídos somente se forem verificados. Dados de elementos de seleção
>   de arquivo não são serializados.

Por isso, o php nunca executava a `query` e retornava vazio, o que ocasionava um erro ao tentar fazer a conversão da string vazia para json.

Logo, você tem três opções:

1 ) Retirar o if.

2 ) Inserir esse valor do botão. Conforme o exemplo:

```
var button = $("#enviar");                 
var result = button.parents('form').serialize() 
    + '&' 
    + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
    + '='
    + encodeURI(button.attr('value'))
;
```

3 ) Colocar os valores explicitamente no `data:`

```
type : 'post',
data : {
    enviar : 'enviar',
    codigo : '1213232',
    dataFinal : '20/08/2015'
    // [...] mais valores
}
```